# Can I have a "remark" after a "lemma" before its "proof"?

Tags: proof-writing, article-writing

I've developed a `lemma` which is accompanied by its `proof`, naturally. But the `lemma` is a little bit complicated and I'd rather present some more explanations about it, before digging into the proof.

I'm an engineering student with pretty trivial experience in formal argumentation. So, I'm wondering whether I can put a `remark` section after the lemma to enlighten the reader about its meaning, then presenting the `proof`.

Actually, as I checked some proofs, authors often consider extra explanations after the proof. But I believe that such explanations are necessary before the proof, in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can do that -- many math textbooks have cases where they state a theorem, then proceed to give some intuition about what it means, applications of it, until finally the proof appears. (In some applied fields it is even the *preferred publication style* to postpone proofs that don't directly illuminate the main message of the article, all the way to an *appendix*).

Just make sure it is clear to the reader that a proof will follow later, so he doesn't think the proof is supposed to be *so obvious* that you don't even deign to give it.

In other words, don't just put "**Remark.**" at the beginning of a paragraph and then start blathering. Write something like

> Before we prove the lemma, let's observe that it doesn't actually contradict the results of the previous section ...

(or whatever).

Comment: Incredibly clear and useful... Especially the last advice to start the remark section.

Answer (score -3):

In my opinion, yes, since etymologically it is a proposition which is taken for granted, and the proof thereof is postponed (λῆμμα = ‘what is taken’ or ‘what is given’).

Comment: -1.  The meaning of a single word in ancient Greek is almost entirely irrelevant to what consititutes good English writing style.  For instance, would you actually have a different opinion about whether inserting a Remark is acceptable if the Lemma were labelled a Proposition instead??

Comment: Absolutely. My opinion (I'm certainly very old-fashioned in this respect) is a lemma should not be proved before the proposition of theorem it is supposed to prepare.